# Jquery .offset().left sometimes returns correct value, sometimes returns 0

Tags: jquery, offset

I am making a site with slides. I've made two divs, one with the width equal to width of screen and the second one (child) 9 times bigger (for 9 slides)

I am using `.offset().left` to set correct values, and in general, my site works great, but sometimes, it stands still

I've found out what is the problem. I've printed the `.offset().left` values into console.log, and it looks like that

```
Refresh no.1: 0
Refresh no.2: 0
Refresh no.3: 1920
Refresh no.4: 0
Refresh no.5: 1920
Refresh no.6: 1920
Refresh no.7: 0
Refresh no.8: 1920
Refresh no.9: 0
Refresh no.10: 0
Refresh no.11: 0
```

Sometimes it's correct, sometimes it's not, and I have no idea why.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider reading this article on how to ask questions in the best way possible to get help faster. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, it is solved, leaving if someone would have the same problem.
It seems that, despite of using

```
$(document).ready
```

it was calculating offsets before the page would load completly

What I've had to do was to replace this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $something1 = $('#something1').offset().left;
        $something2 = $('#something2').offset().left;
        $something3 = $('#something3').offset().left;
```

With this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $k = 1;
  $('#right').on('click',function(){
                if($k == 1){
                    $something1 = $('#something1').offset().left;
                    $something2 = $('#something2').offset().left;
                    $something3 = $('#something3').offset().left;
                    $k = 0;
```